# how to install apache flink on wsl2 ubuntu of windows 11

Tags: scripts, systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Below is my Apache Flink Installation process on wsl2 ubuntu of Windows 11.

First, openjdk-11 installation

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

systemd installation,

```
$ sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf
    
[boot]
systemd=true
```

download and unzip flink-1.18.1 and make link of flink-1.18.1

```
$ ln -s flink-1.18.1 flink
$ pwd 
/home/jhwang
$ ls
flink flink-1.18.1
```

creation of flink.service on /usr/lib/systemd/system

```
$ nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/flink.service
    
[Unit]
Description=Flink Service
    
[Service]
Type=simple
User=jhwang
Group=jhwang
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk
ExecStart=/home/jhwang/flink/bin/start-cluster.sh
ExecStop=/home/jhwang/flink/bin/stop-cluster.sh
    
    
Restart=always
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I execute the systemctl of flink,

```
$ sudo systemctl enable flink
$ sudo systemctl start flink
```

But the flink system daemon is deactivated immediately.

```
● flink.service - Flink Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/flink.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: deactivating (stop) since Fri 2024-02-16 08:33:03 KST; 2s ago
    Process: 248179 ExecStart=/home/jhwang/flink/bin/start-cluster.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 248179 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS); Control PID: 248868 (bash)
      Tasks: 67 (limit: 19187)
     Memory: 257.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/flink.service
             ├─248563 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin/java -Xmx1073741824 -Xms1073741824 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=268435456 -XX:+Ignor>             ├─248868 bash /home/jhwang/flink/bin/stop-cluster.sh
             ├─249273 bash /home/jhwang/flink-1.18.1/bin/jobmanager.sh stop
             ├─249382 bash /home/jhwang/flink-1.18.1/bin/flink-daemon.sh stop standalonesession
             ├─249513 timeout 10 tail --pid=248563 -f /dev/null
             └─249515 tail --pid=248563 -f /dev/null

Feb 16 08:33:01 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 systemd[1]: Started Flink Service.
Feb 16 08:33:01 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 start-cluster.sh[248179]: Starting cluster.
Feb 16 08:33:02 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 start-cluster.sh[248449]: Starting standalonesession daemon on host DESKTOP-7MNP0L0.
Feb 16 08:33:03 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 start-cluster.sh[248751]: Starting taskexecutor daemon on host DESKTOP-7MNP0L0.
Feb 16 08:33:03 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 stop-cluster.sh[249116]: Stopping taskexecutor daemon (pid: 248865) on host DESKTOP-7MN>Feb 16 08:33:05 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 stop-cluster.sh[249382]: Stopping standalonesession daemon (pid: 248563) on host DESKTO>lines 1-21/21 (END)...skipping...
● flink.service - Flink Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/flink.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: deactivating (stop) since Fri 2024-02-16 08:33:03 KST; 2s ago
    Process: 248179 ExecStart=/home/jhwang/flink/bin/start-cluster.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 248179 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS); Control PID: 248868 (bash)
      Tasks: 67 (limit: 19187)
     Memory: 257.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/flink.service
             ├─248563 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin/java -Xmx1073741824 -Xms1073741824 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=268435456 -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-exports=java.base/sun.net.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tool>             ├─248868 bash /home/jhwang/flink/bin/stop-cluster.sh
             ├─249273 bash /home/jhwang/flink-1.18.1/bin/jobmanager.sh stop
             ├─249382 bash /home/jhwang/flink-1.18.1/bin/flink-daemon.sh stop standalonesession
             ├─249513 timeout 10 tail --pid=248563 -f /dev/null
             └─249515 tail --pid=248563 -f /dev/null

Feb 16 08:33:01 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 systemd[1]: Started Flink Service.
Feb 16 08:33:01 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 start-cluster.sh[248179]: Starting cluster.
Feb 16 08:33:02 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 start-cluster.sh[248449]: Starting standalonesession daemon on host DESKTOP-7MNP0L0.
Feb 16 08:33:03 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 start-cluster.sh[248751]: Starting taskexecutor daemon on host DESKTOP-7MNP0L0.
Feb 16 08:33:03 DESKTOP-7MNP0L0 stop-cluster.sh[249116]: Stopping taskexecutor daemon (pid: 248865) on host DESKTOP-7MNP0L0.
```

Does this installation process contain wrong command or miss something? Kindly inform me how to install apache flink on wsl2 ubuntu. Best regards

Comment: I solve it by changing the [Service] type to 'forking' from 'simple'. Then flink daemon is working successfully. Thanks any way!